# What is the Fourier transform of $\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^{n/2}}$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

We have the following Fourier transforms:
$$
{\cal F}\left[\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}\right] = 1/\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2}
$$
$$
{\cal F}\left[\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\right] = -\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2}
$$
$$
{\cal F}\left[\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}}\right] = \frac{1}{9}\sqrt{(k_x^2+k_y^2)^3}
$$

I am interested in obtaining 
$$
{\cal F}\left[\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}\right],\quad 
{\cal F}\left[\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\right],\quad 
{\cal F}\left[\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}}\right]
$$

I would appreciate your suggestion/insight.

Comment: $2D$ Fourier transform? Or $1D$ and, with respect to which variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT** for the last two:
$$
\frac{x}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}} = - \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{1}{(x^2 + y^2)^{1/2}} \right] 
$$
$$
\frac{x}{(x^2 + y^2)^{5/2}} = - \frac{1}{3} \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{1}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}} \right] 
$$
How is the Fourier transform of a function related to the Fourier transform of its derivative?